# TouchableHighlight onpress Android

Tags: performance, react-native

I am using react native to develop a simple Touchablehighlight element with onpress event. iOS is ok to go but Android takes few seconds to load a function each time. I have looked up few possible solutions such as TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableNativeFeedback, etc.

My idea is to click a TouchableHighlight -> call handlePress function -> alert('hello world') under a flatlist

Here is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, TouchableHighlight, Platform, TouchableNativeFeedback, View, Text } from "react-native";

import styles from "./Styles";

// Plugin
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";

class BacktoTop extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _handlePress = () => {
    alert('hello world')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={ styles.container }
        underlayColor={"#ffffff"}
        // onPress={this.props.handlePress }
        onPress={this._handlePress }>
        <FastImage
            source={
                (Platform.OS === 'ios') ?
                    require("../../images/back_to_top.png")
                :
                {
                    // 6 months at least 1 view no deletion
                    uri: 'https://image.ibb.co/grvFS8/back_to_top.png',
                    priority: FastImage.priority.cacheOnly,
                }
            }
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            style={{ width: 35, height: 35 }} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

export default BacktoTop;
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the more view components in the upper level to be rendered, the longer time it takes to load.

After I deleted some of my  in parent and removed onMomentumScrollEnd the reaction is improved.

Thanks.